# How to get AppDelegate instance in React Native JS component?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am creating Hybrid application on React Native for both Android and iOS.

How do I access AppDelegate instance in React Native JS component?

Comment: May i know the reason behind this..

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you should write native module to access AppDelegate.